# KeyError when filtering excel data with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read and filter from excel data in Python. I used the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') 
df['apples'] = (pd.cut(df['apples'],bins=[-np.inf,2,5,np.inf],labels=['WOW','ok','BOB']))
print(df)
```

[This is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hPAY.png)

But KeyError: 'apples' occurs. Do you have any advice about how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[1])`

Comment: It gives the same result: KeyError: 'apples'

Comment: When I tried this one, "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list"
error occurs @MaxU

Comment: So please provide the requested output to find out what is actually being read.

Comment: @OykuA, i'd suggest you to post a link to uploaded Excel file, so we could reproduce this error...

Comment: My actual data is seems almost like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXhRt.png @languitar

Comment: @OykuA, do you expect people to type your data manually from that screenshot? ;-)

Comment: It seems you need `df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=1)` or `df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=1)`

Comment: @OykuA, please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: thank you for your advice @MaxU

Comment: Thank you for your response @jezrael ` df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=1, parse_cols= "Q") ` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you have header with `2` rows, so by default columns of `DataFrame` are created by first row.

So need skip this first row by:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=1)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you also want to modify the xlsx file? Or you just want to read it and apply some code to it?
In the second case you could do:

```
df = df.drop(['apples'])
```

And you can input:

```
inputX = df.loc[:, ['oranges', 'lemons']].as_matrix()
```

It depends what do you want to do with it.